# Convert latitude and longitude to street address using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript

Given the latitude and longitude, how can I convert it to a street address using using the Google Maps JavaScript API?

Comment: search for reverse geocoding, Google Maps API can do this from variety of languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we do in Javascript.Make sure you have Internet connection :),Pass your Latitude and Longitude to displayLocation function.try this url

[google map response](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.1750151,78.039961%20&sensor=true)

```
function displayLocation(latitude, longitude) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var method = 'GET';
            var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
                    + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true';
            var async = true;

            request.open(method, url, async);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    var address = data.results[0];
                    var value = address.formatted_address.split(",");
                    count = value.length;
                    country=value[count-1];
                    state = value[count - 2];
                        city = value[count - 3];
                    alert(city);
                    // document.write(address.formatted_address);

                }
            };
            request.send();
        };

        var successCallback = function(position) {
            var x = position.coords.latitude;
            var y = position.coords.longitude;
            displayLocation(x, y);
        };

        var errorCallback = function(error) {

        };

        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            timeout : 1000,
            maximumAge : 0
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback,
                options);

        }
```

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. I tried but it's not working. please look at the code and help me where I went wrong.

Comment: @Shhivaa show the complete code you have tried..in question section

Comment: Hi, can you help me on this I want driving distance between S and D in bing map in javascript?

Comment: @Shivva if you have got it right plz Mark/Accept the answer :)

Comment: @Shhivaa check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357073/getting-driving-distance-using-bing-maps-api-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me a lot. Accepted it.